# Convert Multiple Python Dictionaries to Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have the following code which retrieves account info for tik tok users who have posted videos with specific hashtags.

The code returns multiple dictionaries which I would like to parse into a pandas dataframe with the dictionary keys as the column headers.

```
from TikTokApi import TikTokApi

hashtag = "ugc"
count=10

with TikTokApi() as api:
tag = api.hashtag(name=hashtag)

print(tag.info())

    for video in tag.videos(count=count):
       print(video.author.as_dict)
```

The resulting dictionaries looks something like this:

```
{'id': '6933', 'uniqueId': 'casiusmonet', 'nickname': 'CasiusMonet'}
{'id': '7106', 'uniqueId': 'oneoffryan', 'nickname': 'TikTok Grw'}
{'id': '7113', 'uniqueId': 'shanmy_c', 'nickname': 'Amy Shan'}
{'id': '6787', 'uniqueId': 'mayaelesse', 'nickname': 'maya'}...
```

Desired pandas dataframe result:

| id | uniqueId | nickname |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6933 | casiusmonet | CasiusMonet |
| 7106 | oneoffryan | TikTok Grw |
| 7113 | shanmy_c | Amy Shan |
| 6787 | mayaelesse | maya |

How can I achieve the above result?

thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just collect the dictionaries into a list and create a DataFrame:

```py
lst = []
for video in tag.videos(count=count):
   lst.append(video.author.as_dict)

df = pd.DataFrame(lst)
print(df)
```